# Nullable foreign key with composite key

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

So, first, i must apply symfony to an existing (and old) database.
It's not very easy and some relationship are pretty complex to implement.

My problem is, I have a many -to- One relationship with a composite key 
In one side, the id_group is defined by default but the id (within the group) can be null

When i try to get a movement with a null id, symfony tell me

> Missing value for primary key id...

The relationship is defined like this.

ACTION :

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gestion\CodifBundle\Entity\Codif",inversedBy="ActionsByOrigin")  
* @ORM\JoinColumns({    
*                   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ref_origin", referencedColumnName="id"),
*                   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ref_group_origin", referencedColumnName="id_group")
*                   })
*/
private $origin;
```

CODIF

```
/**
* inverse Side
* @Type("ArrayCollection<Gestion\SiteBundle\Entity\comAction>")
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Gestion\SiteBundle\Entity\comAction" , mappedBy="origin")
*/
private $ActionsByOrigin;
```

I have made a mistake ? Or it's impossible to do like that ?

Comment: Just to be sure: in your database values,  `id` field has value?

Comment: id has alway a value, but the ref can be null sometime